# Session is not wokring on Server side

Tags: php, session, vpn

i am working on a project where i am facing session problem session created but when i redirect to another page it doesn't appear on next page.if i use same code on my another server then it works fine. i am not able to find solution for it. also i am using a VPN server in this project. i am putting my code below

info.php

```
session_start();
$array = [5,6,7,8,9]; 
$_SESSION['mySession'] = $array;
//print_r($_SESSION); //works fine here
exit(header('location:index_2.php'));
```

index_2.php

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);//getting blank array
```

also below i am sharing my session setting on my server please find the image [image: here is snapshot of session setting]

and i am using PHP Version 7.0.21RC1 (as per phpinfo())

Comment: nope we must call session_start() before getting any session. that is not issue Chris

Comment: where does the VPN server fit in?

Comment: Are you using a load balancer or something else which means that info.php and index_2.php may not be on the same server?

Comment: @Mark_1 that's my suspicion

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header('location:index_2.php');
exit();
```

The `header()` call is not a parameter of `exit()`, see the [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) and [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) manual pages.

---

You've said `setcookie()` is not working, that is the root of your problem - the session ID is sent via a cookie unless you change the configuration and pass it in the URL.  You can test this with

```
// the constant SID is the current session name and id formatted as a string suitable for URLs
header('Location: index_2.php?'.SID);
```

on your first page, and

```
session_id($_GET[session_name()]);    // usually == $_GET['PHPSESSID']
session_start();    //  do this *after* setting the session ID as above
```

in your second page.

Do a search for **`php setcookie not working`** you will get lots of results to look at.  The most common cause of `setcookie()` not working is something being sent to the browser before the `setcookie()` call.  Your search will have plenty of hints for how to deal with this.

Comment: it doesn't work tried already . if the same code works perfect in another server then we must think about apart from this code.

Comment: This construct `exit(header('location:index_2.php'));` is invalid, see the [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) and [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) manual pages.

Comment: If your code works on one server but not on another, there's a difference in the configuration of and/or software on the two servers.  Find that difference, and you will find your answer.

Comment: i have tried  `header('location:index_2.php'); exit(); ` this method too. but still not working

Comment: Look at the configuration of the two servers - where does the VPN fit in?  Are the two files actually on the same physical machine?

Comment: yes both file running on same ip address you can check snapshot.and also session is working in signal page.but when i redirect page to another page it doesn't  work.

Comment: FWIW, you don't have a screenshot posted that shows more than one IP address.  As I said earlier, if your code works on one server but not on another, ***there's a difference between the two servers***, either in the configuration or the software (or both). Find that difference, and you will find your answer.

Comment: i accepted your suggestion  dear @FKEinternet  even i have replaced session configuration code in ini file with my working ini session setting i have done all basic ways and still i am with empty hand .also  i am redirecting on same IP which is in screenshot.

Comment: Wait - you're redirecting to the same IP from both servers? That won't work - sessions only exist on the server where they originated - you can't redirect from one machine to another and expect the session to exist on the target machine, unless you have some outside mechanism in place replicating the session store between the two servers.

Comment: ok let me explain you a bit more i have a main server the ip is 195.39.xxx.xxx and my both file is runnig on  http://172.16.xxx.xxxx now  you can my both session file is on same ip address also. i am using fortin client to connect VPN server. so is there any problem of VPN server. also i am not able to create a cookie using php setcookie function i dont know why it happening .